# Polling TCP connections in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server

I'm working on a school task where i have to make a server that gets TCP connections. Those connections then pass data. I use poll() to see if there is a new connection request or if there is incoming data from an existing connection. It's used with the loop back address (127.0.0.1).

It works fine when i have 1 connection, but when i open a second one, it stops polling and wait for the data from the new connection. 
The strange thing is, that if i open a third connection, it does give the data of that third connection as well, but still no polling, just waiting.

I read a lot about it and i'm stuck on it for a while.

I wrote the server-code in the connmgr.c (with a lot of printf's for finding my mistake). I'll explain below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <poll.h>

#include "connmgr.h"

#define _GNU_SOURCE

static FILE * write_file;
struct pollfd *poll_list;
int serversd;
int conn_counter = 0;

int dplist_errno;

dplist_t * list = NULL;
list_node_t * dummy = NULL;


void * element_copy(void *element);
void element_free(void **element);
int element_compare(void *x, void *y);


void add_poll(struct pollfd * polllist, tcpsock_t *client, tcpsock_t *server){
conn_counter++;
polllist = realloc(polllist,sizeof(struct pollfd)*conn_counter+1);
int clientsd;
tcp_get_sd(client, &clientsd);
polllist[conn_counter].fd= clientsd;
//printf("fd in add_poll = %d \n",clientsd);
polllist[conn_counter].events = POLLIN;
}
    int stop = 0;
    tcpsock_t *server, *client;

void connmgr_listen(int port_number){

    sensor_data_t data;
dummy = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));

write_file = fopen("sensor_data_recv", "w");

poll_list = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
list = dpl_create(&element_copy, &element_free, &element_compare);

if(tcp_passive_open(&server,port_number)!=TCP_NO_ERROR)exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
tcp_get_sd(server, &serversd);

poll_list[0].fd = serversd;
poll_list[0].events = POLLIN;

printf("server fd = %d \n",serversd);

printf("start with fd %d = %d \n", 0,poll_list[0].fd);

int bytes,result;
int test = 0;

while(1){

    test++;
    int sd;
    int return_value,i;

    return_value = poll(poll_list,conn_counter+1,TIMEOUT);

    if (return_value>0){
        if(poll_list[0].revents & POLLIN>0){
            printf("add client\n");

            tcpsock_t * requestclient;
            if (tcp_wait_for_connection(server,&requestclient)!=TCP_NO_ERROR) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            tcp_get_sd(requestclient, &sd);
            dummy->sd = sd;
            printf("inserted sd = %d \n",sd);
            dummy->client = requestclient;
            time(&(dummy->ts));
            list = dpl_insert_at_index(list, dummy, conn_counter,true);



            //printf("sd from client = %d \n", tcp_get_sd(client, &sd));

            add_poll(poll_list, dummy->client, server);
            printf("conn_counter = %d \n",conn_counter);

        }

        //for (i=0; i<conn_counter;i++){
        i=0;
        while(i<conn_counter){
            if(poll_list[i+1].revents & POLLIN>0){

                printf("poll in %d \n",i+1);

                dummy = (list_node_t *) dpl_get_element_at_index(list,i);
                time(&(dummy->ts));
                client = dummy->client;
                sd = dummy->sd;

                /*for(int l = 0; l<conn_counter;l++){
                        printf("sensor %d \n",l);

                }*/

                bytes = sizeof(data.id);
                printf("@ line %d en i = %d \n", __LINE__,i);result = tcp_receive(client,(void *)&data.id,&bytes); 

                bytes = sizeof(data.value);
                printf("@ line %d \n", __LINE__);result = tcp_receive(client,(void *)&data.value,&bytes);

                bytes = sizeof(data.ts);
                printf("@ line %d \n", __LINE__);result = tcp_receive(client,(void *)&data.ts,&bytes);


                if ((result==TCP_NO_ERROR) && bytes){
                printf("sensor id = %" PRIu16 " - temperature = %g - timestamp = %ld\n", data.id, data.value, (long int)data.ts);
                        }

                else{
                    if(result == TCP_CONNECTION_CLOSED){printf("peer left \n");}
                    else{"error in peerconnection \n";}
                    tcp_close(&client);
                    list = dpl_remove_at_index(list, i, true);
                    }
                fflush(stdout);
            }
            if (poll_list[i+1].revents & POLLHUP){
                printf("client disconnected \n");
                poll_list[conn_counter+1].fd=-1;
                poll_list[conn_counter+1].events=0;
                fflush(stdout);
            }i++;
        }       
    }
    //if(return_value<0){exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    //if(stop == 1){break;}
    printf("end of while %d \n",test);



}
```

Once a server has started in the tcp_passive_open, it will start polling untill the return_value is high. Then it checks if the POLLIN is at [0], what means a new connection request. If not, i check all the connections in the poll_list, starting from 1 untill conn_counter. If not, i check for a POLLHUP and set the fd of that client at -1 so poll() will ignore this.

**I think it should be somewhere where i use the while-loop to check if the POLLIN is from one of the connections, because i can add connections no problem.**

the dpl_... functions are from a dubble-linked-list library i wrote myself and should work fine. They create a list, get an element at an index... The list uses 3 callback functions.

The tcp_... functions are functions i've got from the prof. The tcpsock.h file should give enough information:

```
typedef struct tcpsock tcpsock_t;

int get_size_tcpsock();

// All functions below return TCP_NO_ERROR if no error occurs during execution

int tcp_passive_open(tcpsock_t ** socket, int port);
/* Creates a new socket and opens this socket in 'passive listening mode' (waiting for an active connection setup request) 
 * The socket is bound to port number 'port' and to any active IP interface of the system
 * The number of pending connection setup requests is set to MAX_PENDING
 * The newly created socket is returned as '*socket'
 * This function is typically called by a server
*/

int tcp_active_open(tcpsock_t ** socket, int remote_port, char * remote_ip);
/* Creates a new TCP socket and opens a TCP connection to the system with IP address 'remote_ip' on port 'remote_port'
 * The newly created socket is return as '*socket'
 * This function is typically called by a client 


int tcp_close(tcpsock_t ** socket); 
/* The socket '*socket' is closed , allocated resources are freed and '*socket' is set to NULL
 * If '*socket' is connected, a TCP shutdown on the connection is executed
 */

int tcp_wait_for_connection(tcpsock_t * socket, tcpsock_t ** new_socket); 
/* Puts the socket 'socket' in a blocking wait mode
 * Returns when an incoming TCP connection setup request is received
 * A newly created socket identifying the remote system that initiated the connection request is returned as '*new_socket'
 */

int tcp_send(tcpsock_t * socket, void * buffer, int * buf_size );
/* Initiates a send command on the socket 'socket' and tries to send the total '*buf_size' bytes of data in 'buffer' (recall that the function might block for a while)
 * The function sets '*buf_size' to the number of bytes that were really sent, which might be less than the initial '*buf_size'
 */

int tcp_receive (tcpsock_t * socket, void * buffer, int * buf_size);
/* Initiates a receive command on the socket 'socket' and tries to receive the total '*buf_size' bytes of data in 'buffer' (recall that the function might block for a while)
 * The function sets '*buf_size' to the number of bytes that were really received, which might be less than the inital '*buf_size'
 */

int tcp_get_ip_addr( tcpsock_t * socket, char ** ip_addr);
/* Set '*ip_addr' to the IP address of 'socket' (could be NULL if the IP address is not set)
 * No memory allocation is done (pointer reference assignment!), hence, no free must be called to avoid a memory leak
 */

int tcp_get_port(tcpsock_t * socket, int * port); 
/* Return the port number of the 'socket'
 */

int tcp_get_sd(tcpsock_t * socket, int * sd); 
/* Return the socket descriptor of the 'socket'
 */
```

Thank you for reading this and i hope you can help me!

ps, i have still some problems when i disconnect a tcp and then connect with another one, but that are problems for later :)

Answer (score 2):

In your function

```
void add_poll(struct pollfd * polllist, tcpsock_t *client, tcpsock_t *server)
```

You're reallocating the pollfd buffer containing the sockets fd's, but you're getting the result in a temporary pointer variable (polllist) instead of your global variable "poll_list". Realloc may or may not move the memory to another location if it can just extend it.

When you get back into your loop, nothing has changed, you're still using the same buffer -that may have been freed !- containing the server socket and the first connection, and somewhere else in memory, there is a buffer with your 3 sockets.

So either pass a pointer on pointer (struct pollfd **polllist), or set the "poll_list" variable instead :).

Also, if I'm not mistaken, in your loop, when you do :

```
if(poll_list[i+1].revents & POLLIN>0)
```

The ">" operator has a higher priority than the "&" operator, so it's equivalent to :

```
if(poll_list[i+1].revents & (POLLIN>0))
```

Just remove the "> 0", or put parenthesis around your expression

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i changed what you said and it stays the same... i now do  'poll_list = realloc(poll_list,sizeof(struct pollfd)*conn_counter+1);' , but it has no effect. You have any other possible solution? :)

Comment: Beware of your `sizeof(struct pollfd)*conn_counter+1`, as it's equivalent to `(sizeof(struct pollfd)*conn_counter)+1`, not really the same thing as `sizeof(struct pollfd)*(conn_counter+1)`.


Other than that, did you change the `polllist[conn_counter].fd= clientsd;` as well (and the similar line under that) ? And the `POLLIN>0` thing ?


Could you explain what you mean by "that if i open a third connection, it **does give the data** of that third connection as well, but still no polling, just waiting" ?


(Also, make sure you clear the "revent" field when you create a new pollset)

Comment: Yes i did the changes, but that didn't help. I mean that if I open a second connection, it stops polling the first one and just gives data from the the second one. (this happens without polling because it's not looping through the wile-loop anymore, just waiting for data. i can see that because the dummy 'end of while test')
If i open a third connection, it gives the data from the second and the third connection, but again without polling, just waiting for data, not looping through the while. so like you said, maybe there stays a POLLIN flag high?